# Read and writing pandas pivot table to file

Tags: python, pandas

I think I've done this before a while back, but I can't reproduce the code I've written back then and I'm totally facing a blank.

I'm using Python and Pandas to merge, concat, melt and pivot several datasets together into one big dataset.

In the end, I've got a fairly large data set that resides in a pivot table like this:

```
feature    a    b    c
id                    
1        1.0  NaN  NaN
2        2.0  NaN  NaN
3        NaN  3.0  NaN
4        NaN  NaN  4.0
6        NaN  NaN  5.0
```

Cleaning, concat, melting and pivoting the original dataset to the resulting pivot table (as shown in the example above) takes a lot of time. (5 to 10 minutes)

I'd like to write this pivot table directly to a file and load it back into a pivot table the way I saved it, preserving all the headers, indexes. Since it would save me a lot of time.

I've tried to use writing and reading this table using to_csv and from_csv, form_table with no success.

When I load with from_csv or from_table, I end up with results like this:

```
          a    b    c
id                    
1        1.0  NaN  NaN
2        2.0  NaN  NaN
3        NaN  3.0  NaN
4        NaN  NaN  4.0
6        NaN  NaN  5.0
```

or this:

```
       feature a    b    c
id                    
1        1.0  NaN  NaN  NaN 
2        2.0  NaN  NaN  NaN 
3        NaN  3.0  NaN  NaN 
4        NaN  NaN  4.0  NaN 
6        NaN  NaN  5.0  NaN
```

What would be the correct (or quickest) approach to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your first load with `read_csv`, you can set:

```
df.columns.name = "feature"
```

To re-gain the column name.